# Nhibernate one to many relationship error

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am encountering foreign key error while saving child record for parent-child relationship in nhibernate. I am using Mysql as the database.
Value of foreign key column  inserted is "0"

Table

```
CREATE TABLE Company(
   Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Name Varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Client(
   ClientId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   CompanyId INT NOT NULL,
   Name Varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ClientId),
   FOREIGN KEY(CompanyId) REFERENCES  Company(Id)
);
```

Class:

```
public class Company
{
    private IList<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

    public virtual IList<Client> Clients
    {
        get { return clients; }
        set { clients = value; }
    }

    public  virtual void AddClientToCompany(Client client)
    {
        client.Company = this; 
        clients.Add(client);
    }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }   
}

 Company.hbm.xml
   <class name="ConsoleApplication1.Company, ConsoleApplication1"          table="Company">
      <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
       <generator class="native"></generator>
      </id>
      <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String"></property>

      <bag name="Clients" table="Client" lazy="false" cascade="all"     inverse="true">
       <key column="CompanyId"></key>
       <one-to-many class="ConsoleApplication1.Client, ConsoleApplication1"         />
   </bag>
  </class>

Client.hbm.xml

<class name="ConsoleApplication1.Client, ConsoleApplication1"   table="Client">
   <id name="ClientId" column="ClientId" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String"></property>
    <property name="CompanyId" column="CompanyId" type="int" ></property>

    <many-to-one name="Company"  class="ConsoleApplication1.Company,    ConsoleApplication1" 
             column="CompanyId" cascade="none" insert="false"/>
 </class>
```

Sql generated:

> NHibernate: INSERT INTO Company (Name) VALUES (?p0);?p0 = 'Test Company'          [Type:
>   String (12)]
>     NHibernate: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
>
> NHibernate: INSERT INTO Client (Name, CompanyId) VALUES (?p0, ?p1);?p0 = 'Test Client' [Type: String (11)], ?p1 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)]

Runtime code:

```
        Company company = new Company();
        company.Name = "Test Company";

        Client client = new Client();
        client.Name = "Test Client";

        company.AddClientToCompany(client);

        session.Save(company);
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that for both `many-to-one` and `one-to-many` we have to use the same column **`"CompanyId"`**

The `Company.hbm.xml`

```
<bag name="Clients" table="Client" lazy="false" 
     cascade="all" inverse="true" >
  <!-- wrong column name, it must be parent reference in a child table -->
  <!-- <key column="ClientId"></key> -->
  <key column="CompanyId" />
  <one-to-many class="ConsoleApplication1.Client, ConsoleApplication1" />
</bag>
```

The `Client.hbm.xml` - the same column is used for the reversed mapping **`CompanyId`**

```
<many-to-one name="Company"  
             class="ConsoleApplication1.Company, ConsoleApplication1" 
             column="CompanyId" 
             cascade="none"/>
```

Really, there is exactly ONE column (CompanyId) which is responsible for both sides of the mapping... the same principal as a relation in DB

EXTEND:

Once we correct mapping, we MUST be sure, that we do set both sides of the relationship in C#. this is needed, because of **`inverse="true"`** mapping.

The best way is to extend the **`AddClientToCompany()`** to be assigning both sides:

```
public class Company
{
    ...
    public  virtual void AddClientToCompany(Client client)
    {
        clients.Add(client);
        // essential line
        client.Company = this;
    }
    ...
```

And the runtime code:

```
var client = new Client
{
   ...
}
var company = new Company
{
   ...
}
// no company knows about client 
// and client knows abtou company
company.AddClientToCompany(client);
session.Save(company);
```

NHibernate will now properly inject the INSERT with related entity ID...

After all that, what we have to really be sure about, is that the reference mapping is editable - not the property:

```
<property name="CompanyId" column="CompanyId" type="int"
      insert="false" update="false" >
// the above must be insert and update false
// the below must be editable - it is a reference - managed by NHibernate
<many-to-one name="Company"  
      class="ConsoleApplication1.Company,    ConsoleApplication1" 
      column="CompanyId" cascade="none"/>
```

Comment: I tried using the same column  in company.hbm.xml. I am still getting the same foreign key constraint violation error as insert statement tries to insert "0" for "CompanyId" column in client table.

Comment: I do have the same code.
            Company company = new Company();
            company.Name = "Test Company";

            Client client = new Client();
            client.Name = "Test Client";

            company.AddClientToCompany(client);

            session.Save(company); 
        public virtual void AddClientToCompany(Client client)
        {
            client.Company = this;  
            clients.Add(client);
        } ... Still throwing the same error

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the original question with the complete .hbm.xml file  , runtime code and fix to "AddClientToCompany" method.

Comment: The final essential part of our mapping is that `<property>` with `CompanyId` will be `insert="false" update="false"` - but not the Reference **`Company`**.  This is reference managed by NHibernate and that MUST be editable. That's how NHibernate will know, which CompanyId place into INSERT or UPDATE - based on the key recieved for new Company...

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!! insert="false" and "update="false" should be defined in the <property> and not <many-to-one>. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy amazing NHibernate, great tool ;)